# Google cloud Pub/Sub - subscriber not forwarding messages to dead letter topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, dead-letter

I am trying to configure dead letter topic for unack messages to handle failures gracefully, however, it doesn't seem to be working. I tried two approaches:

1. I created a dead letter topic and subscription through google cloud console but it didn't work, though all the permissions were granted and under dead lettering tab everything was blue tick. Also, the topic is a different topic from main topic.
2. Then, I tried to go completely through cloud shell. I created a new project and took a fresh start, still no luck. I followed each and every step mentioned in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control). All the commands were successful and got all the blue ticks again under dead lettering tab.

In both approaches --max-delivery-attempts=5. My understanding is that after 5 attempts subscriber should forward the message to dead letter topic automatically. However, this isn't happening and the unack messages are hanging around in subscription only.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How the messages are consumed and unack?

Comment: Messages are consumed by google-cloud node api, and in some scenario consumer may end up not acknowledging it.

Comment: Could you confirm if you've given Pub/Sub(service account) permission to publish to your dead letter topic as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#assigning_the_publisher_role)?

Comment: I guess you are using a pull subscription, and if the processing is not OK, you answer a nack to the API, correct? And do you see in the logs (if you write that log entry) several nack for the same message ID?

Comment: I had almost the same issue, but my dead-letter topic works, but in my console I can not pull messages from the subscription that has dead-letter topic attached. Tab named messages does not show for it. Subscriptios without dead-letter topic show the tab correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to active this options in your suscriptions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m1PR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).