# Google cloud Pub/Sub - it does not forwarding messages to dead letter topic

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, dead-letter

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141733) already exist but nobody gave a valid solution.

I am trying to configure dead letter topic for unack messages to handle failures gracefully, however, it doesn't seem to be working. I tried through google cloud console:

create topic send-notif-topic
create subscription send-notif-sub (pull) -> enable dead letter queue (all blue tick)
create topic dead-letter-topic
create subscription dead-letter-sub (pull)
I don't ack the massage from send-notif-sub.

from send-notif-sub METRIC you can see the 'Unacked message count' increased, so the message should be forward to dead-letter-topic but in the dead-letter-topic METRIC the "Publish request count" is empty and the dead-letter-sub don't get any messages....

BTW inside the send-notif-sub DETAILS i can see that the "Dead letter topic" is dead-letter-topic. So it should be all good but I don't get anything in the dead letter topic

Comment: Do you have a subscriber on the subscription that receives the messages, but doesn't ack them? Also, did you give subscribe permission on the subscription and publish permission on the dead letter topic to the project Pub/Sub service account?

Comment: Remember that the Message is sent to Dead Letter topic only avec 5 nacks (or more). Did you met that condition?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn I do have a subscription that receives the messages (i do a log for the message) and return before ack them. I also add all the permission from the cloud console and using the cli.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Well i think so, cause the rule is 5 try every 10 secs. It should met the condition , no ?

Comment: Yes it should. If you have a pull subscription, you can query the messages with the UI and you have the number of retries displayed as attribute of the message